# How to create multiple selection checkbox using model field values?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create multiple selection checkbox from model field values and pass the selections to view.

Is there any appropriate method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
classs FormName(forms.Form):

    field_name = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ModelClassName.objects.all(),
                                           to_field_name='model_class_field_name', 
                   widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('タグ名', max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Tag

class MyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return None

        return Tab.objects.filter(name__in=value) 


class TestForm(forms.Form):
    check = forms.MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, empty_label=None)
```

Comment: it will be very helpful if you add some explanation about this.

Comment: This is not giving what I want. I need list of checkbox with value which is from models field values

Comment: Can you give some code and explain what do you want in detail?

Comment: My aim is to create list of checkbox in the "checkbox.html", the checkbox values should be taken from the model's field(say eg: field is data which contain values data1, data2 etc. My checkbox should be data1, data2 etc). If any checkbox is selected and submit the selected options should pass to view.py

Comment: I have changed the form. The values of Tag's name will be rendered as the checkbox.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But no I am facing a new issue with this answer. I can't post the selections to view. When I submit the selections it shows the error "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test all the code. Please check the new code I have added a class.